# Laravel Eloquent Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a sales model defined and when I call `Quote::find('1');` it is not returning my sales object. Have I done something wrong with my relationship? Here is the table structure:

Quote: id, companyName, stage, saleId

Sale: id, name, phoneNumber

```
Class Quote extends Eloquent
{

    protected $with = ['sale'];

    public function sale()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Sale', 'id');
    }
}
```

In my `Sale` model I have defined:

```
public function quote()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Quote');
}
```

Comment: You mean `Sale::find(1)` ?

Comment: No I mean Quote::find(1). I edited my question. It returns the Quote just not the sale.

Comment: Did you called `Quote::find('1')->sale->name` ?>

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Had my relationship backwards.

```
Class Quote extends Eloquent
{

    protected $with = ['sale'];

    public function sale()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Sale', 'saleId');
    }
}
```

To understand it better I think you can say that in a belongs_to relationship, the foreign key resides in the table of the model you are trying to create the relationship from. So the above function could be read like "saleID belongsTo Sale model".

The foreign key resides in the other model's table when using has_one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$quote = Quote::with('sale')->find(1);
```

You should be able to then go something like this `$quote->sale->name`